# Server socket on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, sockets, windows-phone

I'm in the process of porting an application to the Windows Phone platform. I spent quite a while reading MSDN documentation and I can'd find nothing on the subject.

Is it possible to create server sockets on Windows Phone? All I've found is related with client side, like creating connections to remote machines. I can't find nothing the other way: The phone acting as the server.

Some essential methods like Bind and Listen are not exposed by the Socket class included in the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK.

This was kind of a surprise to me.

Any help or confirmation on this will be truly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a socket for listening from a Windows Phone 7 application.  This is due primarily to the complexities of the cellular data networks, such as the use of transparent proxies, shared IP addresses, and frequent connection disruptions.

Answer (score 0):

Until windows phone 8 you will not be able to listen on sockets, you have to use an intermediary service to listen/send between two or more phones.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, on windows phone 8, there is new API introduced for streamlistner
We are also trying at our end, should be possible
Class is StreamSocketListener

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I dont know about a "server" but it has UDP functionality and can send data through it and send/receive with TCP.

also, i have found the SDK to lack some APIs to interface with the phone. ex no Bluetooth or not being able to switch between internal and headphones for sound through developer programming.